# Pre-Caching and Googlebot

Tags: plugin-w3-total-cache, cache, plugin-wp-supercache

There are some wp-plugins which do pre-caching. If Googlebot is coming to crawl a website, what site version is served to it: a dynamic one or the one from server cache, generated through pre-caching?

Comment: google's algorithm afaik is aiming more towards whats better for a normal person. if your 'dynamic' version and your cache version of your site are the same, which they are (only what, 15min difference), the only real difference to Google would be the load speed time. and Google caring about better-for-people would like to see speed. so imho, cache.

Comment: From your Google Search Console account use "fetch as Google" and you can verify exactly what is happening in your unique case.